# Blankspace and colon not found in firstline

Tags: amazon-web-services, xgboost, amazon-sagemaker

I have a jupyter notebook in SageMaker in which I want to run the XGBoost algorithm. The data has to match 3 criteria: 
-No header row
-Outcome variable in the first column, features in the rest of the columns 
-All columns need to be numeric

The error I get is the following:

```
    Error for Training job xgboost-2019-03-13-16-21-25-000: 
    Failed Reason: ClientError: Blankspace and colon not found in firstline 
'0.0,0.0,99.0,314.07,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.48027846,0.0...' of file 'train.csv'
```

In the error itself it can be seen that there are no headers, the output is the first column (it just takes 1.0 and 0.0 values) and all features are numerical. The data is stored in its own bucket.

I have seen a related question in GitHub but there are no solution there. Also, the example notebook that Amazon has does not take care of change the default sep or anything when saving a dataframe to csv for using it later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message indicated XGBoost was expecting the input data set as libsvm format instead of csv. SageMaker XGBoost by default assumed the input data set was in libsvm format. For using input data set in csv, please explicitly specify `content-type` as `text/csv`.

For more information: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/xgboost.html#InputOutput-XGBoost